# Leaflet setView() vs. panTo()

Tags: leaflet

Is there a difference between the actual zooming when using the *setView* and *panTo* methods in Leaflet?

```
map.setView([52, 13]);

map.panTo([52, 13]);
```

The zooming effect looks identical to me, or am I missing something? Are they the same unless you use the optional parameters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference. In fact, have a look at [Leaflet's source code for `panTo`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/5161140e952969c5da27751b79154a2c93f53bfa/src/map/Map.js#L305):

```
panTo: function (center, options) { // (LatLng)
    return this.setView(center, this._zoom, {pan: options});
},
```

And [`setView`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/5161140e952969c5da27751b79154a2c93f53bfa/src/map/Map.js#L):

```
setView: function (center, zoom, options) {
    zoom = zoom === undefined ? this._zoom : this._limitZoom(zoom);
    ...
},
```

As you can see, `panTo()` just calls `setView()` with the map's current zoom level, and `setView()` will also use the map's current zoom level if the second parameter is `undefined`.

Comment: Should look at the source code more often! Great answer, as always, Ivan.

Answer (score 2):

panTo() is an abstraction built over setView() i.e. panTo() is just another way of using setView(). Panning is more popular with gis people and is more understandable than setview, function wise setView allows to set a zoom level in its arguments.